# Issue with 3 "rows" in a layout, middle one being maximized

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am attempting to create a layout with 3 primary rows.  I'm using ActionBarFragment (from v7 compatability).  I've tried every combination of Linear & Relative layouts I can think of.  I got it working when i only had button1, but not when i added Button's 2 & 3.  I've tried wrapping the functionality (EditText & 3 buttons) into a custom View class (extending RelativeLayout with a merge layout file)

**Desired appearance:**

```
| actionbar          |
+--------------------+
| infobar            |
+--------------------+
| staggered          |
| grid view          |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
|          | button1 |
| EditView | button2 |
|          | button3 |
```

**My current results with relative layout surrounding the staggered view & edittext & buttons**

```
| actionbar          |
+--------------------+
| infobar            |
+--------------------+
| staggered          |
| grid view          |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
```

**Results when using a LinearLayout to surround the grid view & edittext/buttons**

```
| actionbar          |
+--------------------+
| infobar            |
+--------------------+
|          | button1 |
|          | button2 |
|          | button3 |
|          |         |
|          |         |
|          |         |
| EditView |         |
|          |         |
|          |         |
|          |         |
|          |         |
|          |         |
|          |         |
```

**My current layout: activity's layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/eventActivityLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AAA" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_text"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.example.EventStaggeredGridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.example.EventCreatePostView
            android:id="@+id/eventCreatePost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
            android:background="#EEE" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Bottom View's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/postRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/postMessageText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttons"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            android:hint="@string/share"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/postMessageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/post" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/attach_photo_from_camera_or_gallery"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/videoButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/attach_video_from_camera_or_gallery"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_video" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `RelativeLayout` as the parent container with the following changes:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/eventActivityLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AAA" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_text"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/infoBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.example.EventStaggeredGridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.example.EventCreatePostView
            android:id="@+id/eventCreatePost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
            android:background="#EEE" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/postRow"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/postMessageText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttons"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            android:hint="@string/share"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/postMessageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/post" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/attach_photo_from_camera_or_gallery"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/videoButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/attach_video_from_camera_or_gallery"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_video" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```